# Surjectivity and homotopy on cylinder

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $f: S^{d-1} \times [0,1] =: C \rightarrow C$ be homotopic to the identity.
Is it surjective ?

I know that it is true for the sphere $\textbf{ie}$ $f : S^{d-1} \rightarrow S^{d-1} $
but I have no idea of the answer for the cylinder.

Comment: Since a constant map $I \to I$ is homotopic to the identity ($I$ is contractible), I think the answer is no.

Comment: Yes it was very simple in fact. Thank you !

Comment: If I add the condition $f(w,0) = (w,0)$ and $f(w,1)=(w,1)$ for all $w \in S^{d-1}$. Is it still false ?

Comment: I think that extra hypothesis changes the answer.  But what have you tried?  And what tools are you familiar with - for example, do you know homology?

Comment: Yes but I am a beginner. I read Hatcher's book (the part on homology).

Comment: (I wasn't notified of your comment.  You should write an @JasonDeVito in the comment if you want me to be notified.  Since you wrote the original post, I think you will be notified when I send this comment.)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f$ misses a point $p$, then necessarily $p = (w,t)$ with $0 < t < 1$. We can write :

$$
f: C \rightarrow C \setminus \{p\}
$$
and the induced homomorphism on homology groups writes :

$$
f_\star: H_{d-1}(C) \rightarrow H_{d-1}(C \setminus \{p\}).
$$

Aside that, we have the classic information on homology groups of $C$ and $C \setminus \{p\}$ :

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
H_{d-1}(C)&= H_{d-1}(S^{d-1}) &\simeq \mathbb{Z}, \\
H_{d-1}(C \setminus \{p\}) &= H_{d-1}(S^{d-1} \vee S^{d-1}) &\simeq \mathbb{Z}^2
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
where $\vee$ designates the wedge sum. Thus, the homomorphism $f_\star$ can be written as :
\begin{equation}\label{fZZ^2}
f_\star: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^2.
\end{equation}

As $f$ let the two spheres $w \rightarrow (w,0), w \rightarrow (w,1)$ invariant, we have :

$$
\text{Im}(f_\star) = \mathbb{Z}^2
$$
which gives a contradiction.

Is it a correct proof?

Comment: In this proof I did not use the fact that f is homotope to identity.

Comment: I'm going to use $g$ for the map $g:C\rightarrow C\setminus\{p\}$.  So, $f=g$ except they have different codomains.  I think it's correct until the part about  $\operatorname{Im}(g_\ast) = \mathbb{Z}^2$.  Rather, because $g$ is the identity on the $t=0$ and $t=1$ slice, it follows that $g_\ast(a) = (a,a)$.  To actually reach a contradiction, compose $g$ with the inclusion map $i:C\setminus \{p\}\rightarrow C$.  (So $f=i\circ g$).  Show that $i_\ast(a,b) = a+b$, then you find that $f_\ast(a) = a$ because $f$ is homotopic to the identity but $i_\ast g_\ast(a) = i_\ast(a,a) = 2a$, contradiction

Comment: Ok I understand. Thank you very much Jason DeVito !